# Cannot load resource files using Scala / Mill

Tags: scala, resource-files, mill

I cannot load resources in Scala, using Mill (0.10.5) as the build tool.

The minimal example is:

```
.
├── app
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── resources
│           │   └── hello_world.txt
│           └── scala
│               └── Main.scala
├── build.sc
└── out
```

with `build.sc`:

```
import mill._, scalalib._, mill.modules.Jvm


object app extends ScalaModule {
  def scalaVersion = "2.13.5"
}
```

and `Main.scala`:

```
import scala.io.Source

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val helloWorldText : Iterator[String] = Source.fromResource("/hello_world.txt").getLines
    helloWorldText.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

While `mill -i app.run` compiles, the program throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource 'hello_world.txt' was not found in the classpath from the given classloader
```

What is the right approach to access resource files using Mill?

Answer (score 0):

Mill `ScalaModule` does not use the Maven/SBT directory layout by default. Instead, it expects the following directory structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── src
│   |   └── Main.scala
│   └── resources
|       └── hello_world.txt
├── build.sc
└── out
```

This is also part of the [Getting Started section](https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/mill/mill/Intro_to_Mill.html#_getting_started) in the documentation.

What you are looking for is a SBT-compatible project layout, which is discussed in the documentation under section [SBT-compatible Modules](https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/mill/mill/Common_Project_Layouts.html#_sbt_compatible_modules). In short, you need to extend from `SbtModule` instead of `ScalaModule`.

Alternatively, you can also override the `sources` and `resources` targets, to customize to your needs.

Comment: Was already mentioned... still didn't work. It's a necessary change, but the slash in the filename has to be removed, too.

Comment: What was already mentioned by whom? What is a necessary change? Which slash in which filename do you mean? Your comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: `"/hello_world.txt"`, the slash is wrong here. I don't remember the user who mentioned it, they sadly deleted their comment.